# how to pass thread object to new activity and get it back at the and

Tags: android, android-activity, parameter-passing

it is possible to pass a thread object to a new activity using intent do some processing and then return the thread to the main activity ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sort answer ... No. Use a Service, more specifically a IntentService/BroadcastReceiver which uses a worker thread, or an AsyncTask .. or RxJava ..

Comment: hi, i am quite new in android but 30 years programming in many language.

Comment: and i do not know very well how to use stakoverflow :)) yet. so i appologize for wrong posting. When i said passing thread a mean to pass the instance of the class how extends the thread. It is possible to pass this class by reference to the activity ?

Comment: Activities have independent lifecycles, I think you have to explain better your use case scenario - I'm sure once you've got a better understanding of the platform then it will be simple. If for example if you want to start activity B from activity A, and return a result to Activity A (A explicitly relies on Activity B's result), then you would use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` - an example of startActivityForResult : http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example Any threading can be handled in the second activity, I suggest AsyncTaskLoader

Comment: Intents only allow serialized Objects (from memory the Framework uses a separate process to pass serialised objects, hence a different memory address space than your App/Activity), so you can't pass a pointer to an Object.  if you want to pass Objects around between Activities then I suggest you use the `Parcelable` interface (or Serializable).  Note: not recommended for big data sets like `Lists` as there a limit on the amount of data that can be marshalled/demarshalled (you'll get a BINDER TRANSACTION FAILED message).

Comment: You said that using intent serialize it is possible to pass the thread class pointeur to the activity. how can i make it ?

Comment: By the way i already use activity in the game to set some parameter. But for data not pointer on class.

Comment: It look like activity are not very flexible. Old java framelayout look easier for me. Even if you have to manage the view visibility. I am surprise that they did not thought about pass class pointeur to activity. But i think it is for memorie purpose at the begining. But not nedded now as mobile are small computer.

Comment: i think it is what you were talking about

Comment: //To pass:
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);

// To retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");

Answer (score 0):

It is contrary to the concept of Android Activity parameter passing. Better not to do this. Use [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) or create standalone class with `Thread` or `AsyncTask` and interact with it, but do not pass thread object to activity.

Comment: Its worth noting that using a Service alone will mean that tasks will still be executed on the Main UI thread - `IntentService` creates an automatic worker thread.

Comment: time to read the documentation. so if i use a service inside the main acticity and one inside they other acticity i could send message to the main activity to excecute the methode i need.

Comment: In fact Using Service is more like using IPC under Unix ? if we considere that every new activity is a processus ?

Comment: Is there a way to use shared memorie like semaphore in android for activity communication ?

Comment: sorry it is more Broadcast Intent how look like IPC. And can be use inside Service.

Comment: Anyway: passing `Thread` object to Activity as `Intent` parameter - is not a good idea.

Comment: @hterrolle You can think of a Service as a Activity without a UI, its mean't to do background and long running tasks.  Yes IPC is possible, in fact Services can run in their own Process, this is denoted in the AndroidManifest.xml.  Activity to Activity communication is done with Intents, these are handled in a different Memory space, hence why direct Activity to Activity communication is not possible (nor should it).  Things to look into: AsyncTask, Service, IntentService & Broadcast Receiver https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of it, you can create a listener for the processing. When the processing is done, you send the response to the listener (implemented by your main activity). You can do this using an AsyncTask (onPostExecute)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. But it's not good practice nor effective. As mentioned by @Andriy Omelchenko use `Thread`( if you know how to manage Thread by yourself to interact with your activity) or `AsyncTask`(which is specially designed for interacting with UI.) Refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z5MZ0jL2BM&t=50s&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=2) link for understanding threading.

Answer (score 0):

I fact acticity is only good if you need passing data not classe reference ?

So the best is to start getting the information and action fron child activity and make a classe for each traitement inside the main activity. So i can do whatever i want and i need. Excep if everything can be donne inside the children activity. We cannot share work ith activity. It start and stop no processus communication netheir instance sharing.

Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the post as i found out that the question was really badly asked.

I found a very simple solution to manage what i wanted to do without passing thread through activity. I fact i was not necessary at all.

Sorry for the derangement. I am not yet familiarized with android.

I use a receiver to receive intent from other activity, very simple, to do the work inside the main activity.

regards and sorry again.